# std::vector holds base class instance and not of a derived class

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have a problem with C++ vector understanding: an object I get from vector is always a base abstract class and not a derived class that was added to it.

1. I have a vector:

   ```
   vector<SceneNode*> children;
   ```

Where **SceneNode** is an abstract class with pure virtual functions.

2. I add an instance of **ImageSceneNode** (that is derived from **SceneNode**) to this vector:

   ```
   lib::ImageSceneNode node(static_cast<TextureAsset*>(test));

   sceneManager.getRoot()->addChild(&node);
   ```

Where **addChild** function is:

```
   void SceneNode::addChild(SceneNode* child) noexcept {
        this->children.push_back(child);
    }
```

3. Later when I iterate the vector the object inside is an instance of **SceneNode** and fails with a "*pure virtual function*" call error:

[image]

Can you please help, thank you!

Comment: you cannot instantiate an abstract class, so you cannot have object of abstract class in your vector!

Comment: He hasn't any objects of an abstract class in his vector, he has pointers to them, which is perfectly valid.

Comment: I know, but he said he had the instances of the pure abstract class, thus my comment...

Comment: `if (false == children.empty)`, that looks like a coding guideline from the distant past, when compilers would not warn about stuff like `if (x = 1)`. In this case, it's even worse, because you already have a `bool` there, i.e. you can just write `if (!children.empty)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "pure virtual function call" error is most commonly encountered with an object that has been destroyed. I note that you're grabbing and holding a pointer to `node`, a variable with local scope. If you're trying to access that object from its pointer in `children` after the function has exited, you're going to run into errors like this one.

Comment: yep in my opinion as the Sneftel said you should do in your step 2 `sceneManager.getRoot()->addChild(new lib::ImageSceneNode(static_cast<TextureAsset*>(test));`

Comment: No, don't do that. `new` is a terrible thing that nobody should ever use.

Comment: @Puppy Even though I agree that the "raw" use of the new operator is discouraged in modern C++ I don't think we should make absolute statements like that. If you know what you are doing using new is (of course) OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was changing the code to use pointers instead of pass by "copy" and introduced this bug which now makes perfect sense...

Comment: @Puppy your statement is not based on any rational premise... You just don't like good old fashioned instantiation, it would be OK if you would not suggest that using new operator is always wrong, as it is not!

Comment: @Puppy: *"Never use owning raw pointers and delete, except in rare cases when implementing your own low-level data structure (and even then keep that well encapsulated inside a class boundary)."* http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/ However, I agree 100% with your statement as far as `new[]` is concerned. For that one I don't see any use case (and I guess Herb Sutter doesn't see one, either).

Comment: @ChristianHackl I don't see here C++11 tag

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg: Which would make the statement even more true, wouldn't it? (Also, the current convention here on SO seems to be that you can assume C++11 unless specified otherwise.) Of course, an even more important guideline for C++, be it 03 or 11, would be: "Avoid dynamic allocation, unless you actually need it."

Comment: @ChristianHackl here this "convention" is specified? There are certain people at SO who state that strict adherence to some not literally spelled convention is preffered over helping people solving their problems... Are you one of them?

Comment: @ChristianHackl: see that the Puppy didn't provide alternative solution. He just decided to argue with mine...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg: Please tell me how *"C++ is a general-purpose programming language based on C. Use this tag for questions about code compiled with a C++ compiler."* somehow means only one particular version of the C++ standard. If you were around here longer, you would see that people often post C++11 code even without the C++11 tag. And in a comment, it's perfectly OK to mention different aspects of a topic. That's one of the differences between comments and answers. FWIW, the link above actually *supports* your original statement, at least the way I understood you.